# OctoberCMS Builder not saving changes

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-builder

I'm very new to October and have inherited a site in it and I'm having a terrible time with it. The support forum isn't very supportive or helpful and I'm not seeing much activity on here but it's worth a shot.

When I try and save a database table created with builder my local site does the following:

[image]

If I do the same thing in live the table saves without issue. I'm 100% stuck on this and cannot get the thing working. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: for status please set default value `0 or 1`, you set it as null, because it either be yes or no. not like null/undefined as you mention its type `boolean`.

Comment: @HardikSatasiya - Yep. That makes perfect sense to me but... the exact same thing works on the test and live sites, just not localhost. I'm currently developing against the test site and cursing every getting involved.

Comment: hmm, maybe it's related to mysql maybe ...

Comment: @HardikSatasiya - that's what I'm thinking but no idea what the setting could be...

Comment: @HardikSatasiya - Someone suggested I disable strict mode but doing so at the OctoberCMS and the MYSQL level does not solve the issue.

Comment: hmmm, then try to compare version from your live and local, and try use same version

Comment: @SpaceBeers what is the MYSQL version? What is the PHP version? Can you save the table if you remove the status column?